# How to use key of a map type column in joining dataframes in spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and not aware of any other preferable way of doing this. I am want to perform INNER join on below data frames.

```
data_frame_1 :

col1 : Int,
col2 : String,
col3 : Map(Int,   Map(Int,Double))

data_frame_2 :

col1 : Int,
col2 : String,
col3 : Int
```

1. I want to join col3's key of outer map of data_frame_1 with col3 of data_frame_2.

**Ex :**

```
data_frame_1 :

col1 : 99999,
col2 : AAAAA,
col3 : Map(4,Map(2, 0.002))

data_frame_2 :

col1 : 99999,
col2 : AAAAA,
col3 : 4
```

I want to join `4` in both data frames. How to join col3 in this way.

```
(data_frame_1.join(data_frame_2, data_frame_1.col("col1") ===  data_frame_2.col("col1") && data_frame_1.col("col2") ===  data_frame_2.col("col2") 

 && data_frame_1.????? ===  data_frame_2.col("col3")  )  )
```

Expected row after join : `[99999, AAAAA, Map(4,Map(2, 0.002)), 99999, AAAAA]`

2. Also please suggest any other way of doing this?

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I have the same problem as you and found this message with no answer :/